LLMA model using Hugging Face: Getting no access
I'm trying to get an LLMA model (meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf ) running in a Docker container via Hugging Face. The corresponding website / blog is, where I got an instruction which I am using: https://www.docker.com/blog/llm-docker-for-local-and-hugging-face-hosting/
Docker runs in Windows 11 Subsystem Linux (WSL) on ubuntu 24.04.
I have a token from Hugging Face for both Finegrained and Read. I have also registered in Meta. With both Hugging Face tokens I get an error message that I have no access:
"Cannot access gated repo for url https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json.
Access to model meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf is restricted and you are not in the authorized list. Visit https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf to ask for access."
What am I doing wrong?
I have to add that I am an absolute beginner with both Docker and LLMA.
